# capture the time immediately after completion of 2business(Eastern Daylight Time) days in Salesforce

Tags: lightning

**IF(ApplicationSent2days__c == NOW(),NOW(),NULL)**

In this formula **ApplicationSent__c** is a DateTime field which populates by Trigger of adding 2 business days to **ApplicationSent__c** formula field.

I want to capture the time immediately after completion of 2business days(Eastern Daylight Time).

But this formula not displaying anything. Is this possible with formula or I have to go with Trigger Please help me with this.

Comment: You can write a formula field, salesforce documentation has formula available. You will easily find it if you search